# Does anyone see any mistakes here? I am trying to get a message via a pipe, from my parent to child

Tags: c, pipe, fork

The problem here is that the child process does not wait for the message to arrive from the function `startWorking()`, and because of that I am getting a random char as output or sometimes nothing.

I am sending a char array from `startWorking()` to the pipe and I am making sure only the parent does this job.

One solution would be, sending a signal from `startWorking()` to the child processor, after writing into the pipe.
But the `read()` function behavior is waiting for the pipe to receive the message and only then read the message, but somehow it's not doing that, or maybe there is a problem in writing the message.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    int mypipefd[2];
    if (pid > 0)
    {
        if (pipe(mypipefd) == -1) 
        {
        perror("Pipe failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        storeEngine(mypipefd);
    } 
    else if(pid < 0) 
    {
        perror("fork call failed \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("I am the child \n");
        printf("child: %d \n", getpid());

        char message[6];
        close(mypipefd[1]);
        read(mypipefd[0], &message, 6);
        close(mypipefd[0]);
        printf("child read value:\n ");
        printf("%s \n", message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
void startWorking(int *mypipefd)
{   
    printf("%d \n" ,getpid());
    //close(*mypipefd);
    write(*(mypipefd+1), "hello", 6);
    close(*(mypipefd+1));
}
```

Notice that if I remove the two slash behind `close(*mypipefd)` the program will never finish, and it will get stuck there.

Comment: I got an old example I made on how to use Fork and Pipe in Linux with and without recursion if you are interested: http://www.acarlstein.com/?p=990. I will check your code in the meanwhile to see if its an easy fix.

Comment: I will check it out, thanks

Comment: In the code, you are closing `mypipefd[1]` which is correct when reading from the pipe; however, after reading, you are closing `mypipefd[0]` which should be only closed when you are thinking to write to the pipe.  I would advice to separate in method when you write and when you read the pipe. Its going to make your code easier to debug and reduce the chances to makes mistakes when working with pipes.

Answer (score 3):

Without examining the rest of your code, you need to call `pipe()` before you call `fork()` so the pipe can be used by both the parent and the child process.  If you call `pipe()` after you call `fork()`, the pipe is only usable by that one process.

More like this:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int mypipefd[2];

    if ( pipe( mypipefd ) == -1 )
    {
        perror("Pipe failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0)
    {
        storeEngine(mypipefd);
    } 
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thank you, it didn't even cross my mind that the problem is from there

Answer (score 0):

No, pipes used to communicate between processes should be created before the fork() (otherwise, you have no easy way to send thru them, since the reading and the writing ends should be used by different processes).